# PHP extract Multidimensional Associative Array Keys as Text

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

With a basic associative array like:

```
$ar = array("First" => 1, "Second" , "Third" =>"Three");
```

if you do:

```
foreach($ar as $key => $val) {

  var_dump($key);

}
```

This will produce:

```
string 'First' (length=5)

int 0

string 'Third' (length=5)
```

How do you Achieve the same results in a Multidimensional Array?

Something like:

```
array( 0 => array(
            "First" => 1, "Two", "Third" => "Three"
                )
     );
```

I tried:

```
foreach($ar as $k => $v){

        var_dump($ar[0][$k]);
        }
```

I got:

```
string 'Two' (length=3)
```

Instead of:

```
string 'First' (length=5)

    int 0

    string 'Third' (length=5)
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ar is equal to this:

```
array( 0 => array(
        "First" => 1, "Two", "Third" => "Three"
            )
 );
```

You could iterate over the inner array to get the same result:

```
foreach ($ar as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
            var_dump($k2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "First"
  int(0)
string(5) "Third"
```

Comment: no, it is not perfect, if the question is talking about "multi-dimensional", then it can even be a wrong answer. It just catered 2-layer depth. Nightmare's answer is a way more correct one.

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_key(&$arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            get_key($value);
        }else{
            var_dump($key);
        }
    }
}
$arr = array(
    'key1'=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>2),
    'key2'=>array('c'=>1,2),
);
get_key($arr);
```

output:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
int(0)
```

Comment: Cool... But Kinda Overkill. Thanx though

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the values of the inner array like this:

```
foreach($ar[0] as $k => $v){
    var_dump($v);
}
```

The problem with yours is that you are only looping over 1 element in the ar array, and then applying that number to the array inside of it.

If you also want to do the same thing on both levels, you need another foreach loop like so:

```
foreach($ar as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $k => $n){
        var_dump($n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion Prints even their VALUES... I Want something like: 
`string 'First' (length=5)

    int 0

    string 'Third' (length=5)` WITHOUT their VALUES.

Comment: What do you mean by without thier values? The only other thing you can get from an array is its key and you just change $v to $k in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can access multidimensional Array keys and indexes like so:

```
$ary = array('whatever' => array('First' => 1, 'Two', 'Third' => 'Three'),
  array('something' => array('cool' => 'yes', 'awesome' => 'super', 'great' => 10)
);
foreach($ary as $k => $a){
  // $k is each Array key within initial Array
  foreach($a as $i => $v){
    // $i is internal index
    // $v is internal value
  }
}
```

Note:

In an Array that contains Arrays the first Array is really the value under key 0, unless the Array is assigned to a key, so your key, 0, is not necessary.

Comment: Cool... though it can make a Beginner NOSE-BLEED!... llz

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array("First" => 1, "Two", "Third" => "Three")
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        var_dump($k);
    }
}
```